# Returning a file stream from a Controller

Tags: mvc-forms, controller, pdf

I have pdf files in folder, I want user enable to download file, in MVC controller its quite simple as below

```
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
```

but it does not work with Sitecore and throws following exception, can anyone give minimal example how it can be achieved.

> OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.

Thanks

Comment: It works good for me in sitecore 9. Did you try to change mimetype to System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf ? Do you have forceDownload=true in <mediaType name="PDF file" extensions="pdf"> node of config? What do you have as a result, any errors?

Comment: It does not work, I updated my question with error thrown

Comment: Do you have a call stack for the exception? It might give important clues as to whether it's thrown before, inside, or after your File() call, and what code is responsible.